# XCOPY exclude list ignored after first exclusion

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have a batch file I've created which uses xcopy to copy a dir, and child dirs, and merge them into one file. (ie. all my modulised development css stylesheets merged into one production stylesheet).

Everything is good, apart from the fact that when I reference the excludelist.txt, it only excludes the first line, and not the subsequent files I want excluded.

Anyone fancy a crack at this? You'd be most helpful.

Here's the code:

```
XCOPY C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT\css\*.* C:\temp /S /I /Y /EXCLUDE:C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT\exclude.txt
```

...and inside my exclude.txt is...

1.css
2.css
3.css
4.css
5.css

///// I know the code works (to an extent) because it is infact excluding file 1.css -- just not the ones below it. Am I right to put each exclusion on a new line?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this in the end?

Comment: I managed to get it to do what I wanted, though not by using the exclude list. 

I copied across everything and then ran a bunch of del commands to remove the files I didn't want. rd would also work for anyone who wanted to remove dirs. eg. 'del C:\temp\1.css /q'

Although this is an acceptable workaround, it would still be nice if someone could solve it.

Thanks Andy.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following,

```
xcopy "C:\users\dad\*.*" dad /s /d <yesnoyesno /EXCLUDE:excluexclu 1>cop.txt 2>err.txt
```

as somewhere on the web I saw a note to the effect that the `/Y` switch could not be used directly with an exclude file.

What I wanted to point out here, was the useful output files 1 & 2, which detail the success & failure issues.

Mine shows only success.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: Create a new text file, type the entries and save the file.

The longer explanation: I ran into this very issue on a Windows 2008 server today.  I tried all kinds of things to get it to work.  Forced notepad to save the file as ANSI, Unicode and UTF-8 but all of them had the same problem.  Finally I started thinking about the fact that I put the file on the server via FTP and it's quite likely that FTP tweaked the file format.  I created a new text file on the server, typed all the same entries in the new file and now it works.

Comment: I had spaces on the end of each line that was causing a problem. Use notepad. make sure there's no trailing spaces or anything unexpected in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I was trying to exclude all files with a certain extension in the root folder and any sub-folders and it didn't work. The reason was I was putting *.pdb instead of just .pdb. The newline/carriage return thing was a total red herring for me.

So my file just looked like:

.pdb
.obj
.vb
.cs

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for when I googled my question =D

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using xcopy correctly - each exclusion file (or match depending on wildcards) should be on a new line within the file. So far I've been unable to reproduce the behaviour you're experiencing.

Is the exclude.txt listing you've given above a test file, or are they the actual css names?
What are the names of the other files that your batch file is supposed to copy?

**Edit:**
That the xcopy is failing to exclude further files after a single match is giving me most pause. I thought it might be to do with the type of carriage-return that was used in the exclude file, but xcopy handles unix-style carriage-returns just fine.

Can you re-verify that the correct exclude file is being used?

Comment: Hey Andy,

1.css, 2.css etc are just file names to illustrate the problem.
The other names of the files that the batch is supposed to copy are all english names, no spaces, no special characters (apart from a '-' (dash).

Hope you have a little more insight. I'm stumped!

Comment: Were you perhaps using U+000A as line separator, instead of U+000A U+000D?

Comment: I just hit enter to get a new line. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing it to save with ANSI encoding on your text editor. 
I was having a similar issue and that did it.